# XSLT 1.0 Nested Grouping, Sum & Count

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

In XSLT 1.0 need to group by Address and then by Part and total. Currently if the part is not included in the first address element then it is omitted. Very new to this.

Output is -

```
Total Units 7

name1address1
part1 Total Pallets : 1
part2 Total Pallets : 2

name2address2
part1 Total Pallets : 2
part2 Total Pallets : 1
```

Should Be - (Note Part 3 in Address 2)

```
Total Units 7

name1address1
part1 Total Pallets : 1
part2 Total Pallets : 2

name2address2
part1 Total Pallets : 2
part2 Total Pallets : 1
part3 Total Pallets : 1
```

XML is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dispatch>
    <delivery>
        <name>name2</name>
        <address>address2</address>
        <pallet>
            <part>part1</part>
        </pallet>
        <pallet>
            <part>part2</part>
        </pallet>
    </delivery>
    <delivery>
        <name>name1</name>
        <address>address1</address>
        <pallet>
            <part>part1</part>
        </pallet>
        <pallet>
            <part>part2</part>
        </pallet>
        <pallet>
            <part>part2</part>
        </pallet>
    </delivery>
    <delivery>
        <name>name2</name>
        <address>address2</address>
        <pallet>
            <part>part1</part>
        </pallet>
        <pallet>
            <part>part3</part>
        </pallet>
    </delivery>
</dispatch>
```

XSLT is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

    <xsl:key name="delivery_detail" match="delivery" use="concat(name,address)"/>
    <xsl:key name="delivery_detail_part" match="pallet" use="concat(../name,../address,part)"/>


    <xsl:template match="dispatch">
        <xsl:variable name="total_units" select="count(delivery/pallet)"/>
        <value>Total Units </value>
        <xsl:value-of select="$total_units"/>
        <br/>

        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="delivery[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('delivery_detail',concat(name,address))[1])]">
            <xsl:with-param name="total_units" select="$total_units"/>
            <xsl:sort select="name"/>
            <xsl:sort select="address"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="delivery">
        <br/>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="address"/>
        <br/>
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="pallet[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('delivery_detail_part',concat(../name,../address,part))[1])]"
        > </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pallet">
        <xsl:value-of select="part"/>
        <xsl:variable name="total_pallets"
            select="count(key('delivery_detail_part', concat(../name,../address,part)))"/>
        <value> Total Pallets : <xsl:value-of select="$total_pallets"/></value>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the pallet template only to the children of the **first** delivery in the name/address group. Try changing this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates
    select="pallet[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('delivery_detail_part',concat(../name,../address,part))[1])]"> 
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates
    select="key('delivery_detail', concat(name, address))/pallet[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('delivery_detail_part',concat(../name,../address,part))[1])]">
</xsl:apply-templates>
```